# NSData is returning null even when nsurl and nsstring are returning proper values

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsurl

I have done the following code to get car_image from response obtained on hitting api.I have a url as value for key car_image.Till,now everything works fine.

Code:

```
-(void)callService{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",@"application/json", nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dict setValue:@561 forKey:@"did"];
    [manager POST:@"http://demo.esenseit.in/Alec1-Admin-Panel-and-API/alec_api/index.php?flag=get_car_list" parameters:dict progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"response %@",responseObject);
       responseArr = [responseObject valueForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *urlstr=[[responseArr valueForKey:@"car_image"]objectAtIndex:1];
         NSLog(@"value of urlstr %@",urlstr);
       // NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr]];
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
        }
        NSLog(@"value of url %@",[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr]);
        NSLog(@"value of data %@",data);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });
    }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  *_Nullable task, NSError  *_Nonnull error) {

              NSLog(@"request failed %@",error);
          }];
}
```

Problem:

The value of data returns as null. I am not able to understand when string, url are all returning their values nicely, then why only data is creating null result.

Log Values:

```
1)value of urlstr demo.esenseit.in/Alec1-Admin-Panel-and-API/alec_api/upload/car_8_1514810479.jpg
2)Error is The file “car_8_1514810479.jpg” couldn’t be opened.
3)value of url demo.esenseit.in/Alec1-Admin-Panel-and-API/alec_api/upload/car_8_1514810479.jpg
4)value of data (null)
```

Comment: According to the output the scheme of the URL (`http://`, `https://`) seems to be missing. And **never** load data from a remote URL with `dataWithContentsOfURL`. It blocks the current thread.

Comment: Thanks ,this helped.